# Registry.LocalMachine returns null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am using ASP.Net Core 2 Identity along with Identity Server 4 to manage users and login for my application.

I am configuring a Kestrel hosted Identity Server as per the [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/windows.html) with the following code:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder().UseKestrel()
                   .UseUrls("http://localhost:44333")
                   .UseStartup<IdentityStartup>();
host.Build().Start();
```

`IdentityStartup` contains the following setup for ASP.Net Core Identity:

```
services.AddIdentity<UserAccount, Role>()
            .AddEngineEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDBContext>();
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\"));
```

When the Web Host is run, I get a Null Reference Exception in [`RegistryPolicyResolver`](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/blob/46dadbb18683164a918873f43624aee3b5b0510c/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection/RegistryPolicyResolver.cs) in Asp.Net Core Identity in the `_getPolicyRegKey` delegate, specifically when the registry key is read with:

```
_getPolicyRegKey = () => Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DotNetPackages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection");
```

By downloading the Microsoft symbols I can see that `Registry.LocalMachine` is returning null, giving the exception on this line.

Is there any way to get `Registry.LocalMachine` to return a correct value, or, preferably, is there any way to override or turn off using the Registry all together?

I note that `IRegistryPolicyResolver` is internal so I can just add my own version of it, and `AddDataProtectionServices` in `DataProtectionServiceCollectionExtensions` is private and always called so I can't override that

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?tabs=aspnetcore2x):

> ### Warning
>
> If you change the key persistence location, the system will no longer automatically encrypt keys at rest since it doesn't know whether DPAPI is an appropriate encryption mechanism.

And [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest#data-protection-implementation-key-encryption-at-rest) says:

> ### Note
>
> If you specify an explicit key encryption at rest mechanism, the data protection system will deregister the default key storage mechanism that the heuristic provided. You must specify an explicit key storage mechanism, otherwise the data protection system will fail to start.

I can't say for sure this is the problem you are having (it seems more like you found a bug), but the prescribed solution in the docs (at least for the first issue) is to use one of the `ProtectKeysWith*` methods:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\"))
    // searches the cert store for the cert with this thumbprint
    .ProtectKeysWithCertificate("3BCE558E2AD3E0E34A7743EAB5AEA2A9BD2575A0");
```

or

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\"))
    // all user accounts on the machine can decrypt the keys
    .ProtectKeysWithDpapi(protectToLocalMachine: true);
```

Comment: I'm not sure the persist keys methods are related to this section. Looking at the source, they set up a key store separate to the registry setup. The section that's causing the issue is separate to the others.

Comment: It's been awhile since I used DPAPI, but IIRC it is tightly coupled to the user account that the application runs under as well as to the registry. If the user account doesn't have permission to open the registry key, it *should* throw an exception, but there might be a bug here where it returns null instead. I don't think it is possible to use DPAPI with the default IIS user account - see the comments under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44714438/181087).

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings#data-protection-default-settings), the using the registry is a fallback if the user profile is not available (which will happen if you are using one of the default IIS Windows user accounts).

Comment: Looking at the [`DataProtectionBuilderExtensions`](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection/DataProtectionBuilderExtensions.cs) all the various `Persist*` and `Protect*` methods seem to do is configure the `KeyManagementOptions` with various `XmlEncryptor` instances based on what is selected. The error I'm getting occurs from the `Configure` method of [`KeyManagementOptionsSetup`](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/blob/rel/2.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection/Internal/KeyManagementOptionsSetup.cs).

Comment: `KeyManagementOptionsSetup` is another internal class so I can't replace it and is created by a private method in `DataProtectionBuilderExtensions`. That is always called even when `AddDataProtection` isn't explicitly set in my application.